# { "status": "Authorization Token not found" }with 200 ok Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two type of user one for the back (user) and the other (marchand) for the front mobile app with flutter .the marchand was added by the user from the back and the marchand must use the login and the pw that the user gived him.my problem that when i want to test authentificate api for marchand the request is always { "status": "Authorization Token not found" }with 200 ok.i dont know where is the problem.plz help me .thankyou.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use JWTAuth;
use App\Models\Marchand;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ApiController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('jwt.verify');
      

    }
   
 
    public function authenticate( Request $request)
    {
       
       $credentials = $request->only('login', 'password');
      
      
        //valid credential
        $validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
            'login' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|max:50'
        ]);
        //Send failed response if request is not valid
        if ($validator->fails()) {
         //   dd($validator);
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->messages()], 200);
        }

        //Request is validated
        //Crean token
        try {
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Login credentials are invalid.',
                ], 400);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return $credentials;
            return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Could not create token.',
                ], 500);
        }
    
        //Token created, return with success response and jwt token
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'token' => $token,
        ]);
    }
```

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'marchands',
           // 'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
     ],

     /*  'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users',
         ],*/
     
            'marchands' => [ // Add new staff provider
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Marchand::class,
        ],
       /* 'marchands' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'marchands',
         ],*/
    ],
```

```
Route::post('login', [ApiController::class, 'authenticate']);
```

```
'jwt.verify' => \App\Http\Middleware\JwtMiddleware::class,
        'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken',
        'jwt.refresh' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken',
        'auth.jwt'=>\App\Http\Middleware\JwtMiddleWare::class,
```

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
//use Throwable;
use Response;
use Exception;
use Throwable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
       /* $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });*/
         $this->renderable(function(TokenInvalidException $e, $request){
            return Response::json(['error'=>'Invalid token'],401);
        });
        $this->renderable(function (TokenExpiredException $e, $request) {
            return Response::json(['error'=>'Token has Expired'],401);
        });

        $this->renderable(function (JWTException $e, $request) {
            return Response::json(['error'=>'Token not parsed'],401);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Personal recommendation, if there is a validation error, do not return anything between 200 and 300... return normal 422, it is an error, not a success.

Comment: I suspect this error is coming from the `JWT` middleware and is a result of you not setting the `Authorization` header.